# Matplotlib doesn't render data exactly square

Tags: python, matplotlib, imshow

I'm using matplotlib.imshow to render a 2D numpy-array of integer-values as a heatmap. The problem is that the pixels in the final image are not entirely square. Sometimes they're a little bit rectangular. This is a big problem for me as I'm using this "heatmap" as an overlay in a map and this behaviour creates a weird visual glitch.

[image]

I'm rendering it like so:

```
fig = plt.imshow(data2d, cmap=cmap, norm=norm, aspect='equal', interpolation='none')
plt.axis('off')
fig.axes.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
fig.axes.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)
fig.axes.set_adjustable('box-forced')
plt.savefig("output.png", bbox_inches='tight', pad_inches=0, dpi=72)
```

I thought setting the "aspect"-attribute to "equal" would take care of making the pixels exactly square. I've noticed that if I increase the DPI the effect is less noticeable as there are more pixels to work with but the rendering-time then becomes an issue.

I'd be glad if someone could point me in the right direction.

Comment: matplotlib has to resample your data onto the pixels on the canvas.  By default it does this by nearest neighbour interpolation.  If you want this to be precise, make sure the size of the axes is such that it is an integer multiple or divisor of the number of data points you have in each direction.

Comment: But why aren't all the pixels the same size? I'm not specifying the size of the canvas

Comment: The canvas pixels are the same size (unless you have a stretched-ratio monitor or something).  Your data pixels just don't divide into them evenly.  
Consider one dimension that is 2 inches long.  At 72 dpi you have 144 pixels.  If you map 10 data pixels into those 144 canvas pixels, some will be 14 pixels, but four of them will be 15 pixels.

Comment: If you don't specify the size of the canvas, a default size is used depending on whats in your matplotlibrc.

Comment: Hm alright I think I understand the problem. Is there a way of telling matplotlib to use a canvas-size so that it fits the underlying data instead of a default one?

Comment: Of course it can be done, but not trivially.  I think PIL etc are better at direct image manipulation than matplotlib.  Matplotlib is meant for displaying data, and the usual presumption is that the dpi of the figure oversampled the images well enough that pixel offsets aren't apparent.

Comment: You can set your figure size = (npixels / dpi * upsamplerate, mpixels / dpi * upsamplerate), and then position the axes at (0, 0, 1, 1).

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing is replacing matplotlib with rasterio and handling the colormap myself. It's definitely not an easy solution...